# Django can't assign to operator

Tags: django

I'm trying to create a shipping list application. Every user has one shipping list and I want to limit the number of items they can have on their shipping list.The number of items is based on the field number in the shippinglist and the default they can have is 5

I'm trying to create a function . If the number of items is less than the shippinglist value number which is 5. Create the number of items left .

So example if their is only 1 items and the default value of the shipping list is 5 . Create 4 more .

```
 can't assign to operator
```

and can someone please help me with function .

```
class ShippingList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=5,default =5)

class Item(models.Model):
    shippingList= models.ForeignKey(ShippingList)
    item= models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True,default=5)
```

views

```
def shippinglist(request):
    s= ShippingList.objects.get(user=request.user)
    l = Item.objects.filter(ShippingList=s).count()
    if s.number < l:
        s.number - l = answer
        for 1 in answer:
              List.objects.create(shippingList=s)
    return render(request,'shippínglist.html',)
```

Comment: which line of your code throws this error?? And better use IntegerField for number.

Comment: @Jingo s.number - l = answer

Comment: s.number - l = answer, not going to work

Comment: 1. Place the variable on left side of the operation.
2. In for loop, assign individual item to a variable no a literal (like in this its 1)
3. You cannot loop over a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These 3 lines have several problems:

```
    s.number - l = answer
    for 1 in answer:
    List.objects.create(shippingList=s)
```

One is the indentation: after `:` the next line must be indented further.

Other is that the control variable is actually a number! That is a `1` not an `l`.

Other is that the left side of the first line is not assignable, because it is the result of a computation, not a name. I think you have the assignment mirrored.

And other is that `answer` (if it is intended to be a number) is not iterable; you probably want to use `range`.

Something like:

```
    answer = s.number - l
    for i in range(answer):
        List.objects.create(shippingList=s)
```

Comment: @UncleToby: You knew it's a 1? And what did you expect it to do? Now, as it happens, `s.number` is a string (type `unicode`) and you are substracting a number... I think you should read a bit about plain Python in general before dealing with Django.

Comment: sorry , I take that back . I went back reading my code and its a l not a 1 .